# php send mail local not woking?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I tried to send mail in localhost.

but working.
i change the php.ini

```
       [mail function]
        SMTP=SMTP.gmail.com
        smtp_port =587
        sendmail_from =postmaster@testmail.com
       sendmail_path = "C: \xampp\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

this my php mail function

```
          public function sendMail($to,$subject,$from=null,$headers = null)
            {
              if($headers == null) {
               $headers = $this->setMimes();
                 }
               $headers .= $this->setFrom($from);
                return mail($to,$subject,$this->getMessage(),$headers);
           }
```

this mail not sending.

Comment: Whats the specific error?

Comment: `sendmail_path = "C: \xampp\sendmail.exe\" -t"`   is that path correct? has a space after `C:`

Comment: Do you have internet connection? :) :) ha ha

Comment: @VinothBabu lmao if hes trying to send it online your right ..

Answer (score 0):

To check/change your PHP mail configuration:

Open your php.ini file (if you don't know where this is, see below) Search for the line that reads [mail function] Add/change the details of your mail server. This could be a local mail server or the mail server of your ISP. Save/close the php.ini file Restart your web server

An example of what the mail settings could look like when you first open the php.ini file:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
;sendmail_path =
```

Additional info is in echoing phpinfo() you can view your PHP configuration details. You can do this by creating a .php file with the following line on it: . When you run this in your browser, you will see a full list of PHP configuration variables. Simply search for the lines that contain php.ini and sendmail_path to see the values you need to use.

Another idea is you might use ini_set() to properly config your mail setting like this

Add the following code to the top of your email script if your mail script continues to fail.

```
// Please specify your Mail Server - Example: mail.example.com.
ini_set("SMTP","mail.example.com");

// Please specify an SMTP Number 25 and 8889 are valid SMTP Ports.
ini_set("smtp_port","25");

// Please specify the return address to use
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'example@YourDomain.com');
```

Comment: hai i changed to my php $to = "vksuriya2007@gmail.com,$subject = "Hi!,$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
echo("Message successfully sent!" } else {
echo("Message delivery failed…"); },this function display message successfully sent,but not reciveing mail.pl;z help me.

Comment: is ur smtp mail setting properly config.

Comment: plz explain .i cannot understand.already, i changed only php.ini only

Comment: did you check your spam folder?